# defer.promise printing out object and not data

Tags: angularjs

I have this code:

```
app.factory('loadDependencies', function ($q, $timeout) {

    return {
        load: function () {
            console.log("start 1");
            var defer = $q.defer();


            $timeout(function () {
                defer.resolve({ resolve: "got dependencies" });
            }, 3000);

            return defer.promise;

        }
    }
});
```

But the problem is that defer.promise doesn't wait until timeout ends, and it also just print out the object properteis and not the data, it prints out :

```
Object { then: qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.then(), catch: qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.catch(), finally: qFactory/defer/deferred.promise.finally() }
```

I'm new to angular and trying to understand what did i do wrong?

**edit**

Some more info about what i was trying to accomplish.

I have a resolve in route that supposed to dynamically load controllers and css files.

```
.when('/url', {
        templateUrl: 'someview',
        controller: 'somecontroller',
        resolve: {
            load: function (loadDependencies) {
                loadDependencies.load(); // here i need to know get the result of what's inside $timeout of 'load'
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: As you can see i your own example you are returning a promise. What you are getting is a pending promise that will be resolved after 3 seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to delay the return until the promise is resolved?

Comment: Why would you. Whats the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `defer.promise` does not return your data and also does not wait until your `timeout` is completed. So what do you do with it is assign some handlers and wait for it to complete/fail:

```
function success(data) {
    //this is called after defer.resolve({ resolve: "got dependencies" }); gets executed
    //here you can access your data
}

function error(error) {
    //this is called if the promise gets rejected
}

loadDependencies.load().then(success, error);
```

Now when your promise completes, it automatically calls one of those handlers. There are more possibilities to apply callbacks, such as the `.finally()` method. Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

**EDIT:**

Just return the promise in your resolver:

```
.when('/url', {
        templateUrl: 'someview',
        controller: 'somecontroller',
        resolve: {
            load: function (loadDependencies) {
                return loadDependencies.load(); // here i need to know get the result of what's inside $timeout of 'load'
            }
        }
    })
```

Now the controller will be called after the promise is resolved and angular will pass the resolved value to it like so:

```
app.controller("CtrlName", function($scope, load){
    //access your load value here
});
```

Comment: But what's the difference? You'll get a pending promise right away, right?

Comment: Yes, but it seemed to me that OP didn't get `promises` right, that's why I wanted to explain them. Without knowing more details, there is no way to give a concrete answer at this point.

Comment: i've edited the question , hopefully it'll clear a bit about what i'm trying to accomplish